# Add to all Strings in an arraylist different letters

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an issue I know I can solve just using an array but that makes a later part of the program more challenging.
Im reading off of a datafile a bunch of letters spaced out. i want to sort them into columns, the data file shows this:

```
[J]             [F] [M]            
[Z] [F]     [G] [Q] [F]            
[G] [P]     [H] [Z] [S] [Q]        
[V] [W] [Z] [P] [D] [G] [P]        
[T] [D] [S] [Z] [N] [W] [B] [N]    
[D] [M] [R] [J] [J] [P] [V] [P] [J]
[B] [R] [C] [T] [C] [V] [C] [B] [P]
[N] [S] [V] [R] [T] [N] [G] [Z] [W]
```

I keep on getting an error on line 18. "

```
   java -classpath .:target/dependency/* Main
[J]             [F] [M]            
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

```
1 import java.util.*;
2 import java.io.*;
3 public class Main {
4 public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
5    String line; 
6    ArrayList<String> C = new ArrayList<>();
7    String a = "";
8    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("dat.dat"));
9    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
10        line = input.nextLine();
11      if (line.indexOf("[") != -1)
12      {
13        System.out.println(line);
14        a = "";
15        for(int lcv = 1; lcv < line.length() - 1; lcv+= 4)
16          {
17            a = line.substring(lcv, lcv+1);
18            C.set(lcv/4, C.get(lcv/4) + a);
19          }
20      }
21      }
```

how would i go about doing this?
I don't want to use a regular array because i'm going to be shuffling these strings around later on.

Expected output: the list will look like

```
JZGVTDBN
 FPWDMRS
   ZSRCV
 GHPZJTR
FQZDNJCT
MFSGWPVN
  QPBVCG
    NPBZ
     JPW
```

Comment: `C.set(lcv/4, C.get(lcv/4) + a)`!?

Comment: You question will also be viewed by others.  So please show the expected output for you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to modify the existing element in your `ArrayList` instead of adding a new element. That's why you're getting the error on line 18.

First, you must **add** the element in the `ArrayList` and then you can **update** it at the index you want.

Also, you can initialize your `ArrayList` by adding empty elements based on the length of `line`.

```java
C.add(a);
C.set((lcv / 4), C.get((lcv / 4)) + a);
```

Your end result should look something like this:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String line; 
        ArrayList<String> C = new ArrayList<>();
        String a = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("dat.dat"));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine();
            if (line.indexOf("[") != -1) {
                System.out.println(line);
                a = "";

                // Init the ArrayList
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length() / 4; i++) {
                    C.add("");
                }

                for(int lcv = 1; lcv < line.length() - 1; lcv+= 4) {
                    a = line.substring(lcv, lcv+1);
                    // Add the new element into the ArrayList
                    // and update it later
                    C.add(a);
                    C.set((lcv / 4), C.get((lcv / 4)) + a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code works great, with the final column it sets it to 
"J     JPW" when i want it as just 
"     JPW"
what should i do

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to use a `Map`. Then you can use [Map.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) to build the column strings.

```
List<String> list = readFile("dat.dat");
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[J]             [F] [M]            
[Z] [F]     [G] [Q] [F]            
[G] [P]     [H] [Z] [S] [Q]        
[V] [W] [Z] [P] [D] [G] [P]        
[T] [D] [S] [Z] [N] [W] [B] [N]    
[D] [M] [R] [J] [J] [P] [V] [P] [J]
[B] [R] [C] [T] [C] [V] [C] [B] [P]
[N] [S] [V] [R] [T] [N] [G] [Z] [W] 
JZGVTDBN
 FPWDMRS
   ZSRCV
 GHPZJTR
FQZDNJCT
MFSGWPVN
  QPBVCG
    NPBZ
     JPW
```

Method to process input file and return List of strings.

```
public static List<String> readFile(String file) {

    Map<Integer, String> columnMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    try {
        Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Path.of(file));
        stream.forEach(line -> {
            if (line.indexOf("[") != -1) {
                System.out.println(line);

                for (int lcv = 1; lcv < line.length() - 1; lcv += 4) {
                    String letter = line.substring(lcv, lcv + 1);
                    columnMap.compute(lcv / 4,
                        (k, v) -> v == null ? letter // init to letter if null
                                : v.concat(letter)); // else append letter
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(columnMap.values());
}
```